# Differentials and True Change

Tags: differential

If z=x^2+y^2, find both dz and delta z, as well as the error that one commits if dz is used instead of delta z.

So far I have dz=2xdx+2ydz.

However, I am not sure how to calculate delta z. Also not sure what the error would be.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using function notation, Let $f(x,y)=z=x^2+y^2$.
Then $\Delta z=f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)$.

To compare $dz$ and $\Delta z$, use $dx=\Delta x$ and $dy=\Delta y$.

Comment: So would Δz=(x+dx)(y+dy)-(x^2+y^2)?

Comment: Actually $\Delta z=((x+dx)^2 +(y+dy)^2)-(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: Ok, therefore, Δz=2xdx+2ydy+(dx^2+dy^2). So the error would just be (dx^2+dy^2)? Thanks